# Weblogic WorkManager policies across war to ejb-jar

Tags: weblogic, workmanagers

I have a servlet that is employing the defaultWM for Weblogic.  This servlet in turn calls an ejb.  This ejb is associated with a different WM ( WM_EJB ).  What I'd like to know, when a thread comes in to be processed via the servlet, does the servlet use the defaultWM and then the carry the same WM context to the ejb call? or is there a switch?

i.e.

1. External request to ServletA -- ServletA is configured with DefaultWM
2. ServletA processes request and call EJB.helloWorld()
3. EJB.helloWOrld() is configured with WM_EJB workmanager

Does the entire process use the DefaultWM or does it switch on the call to EJB.helloWorld()

My apologies if this was answered somewhere else, i couldn't find an answer to WM flow.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some investigations on this and my response is that Weblogic *will switch over from DefaultWM to the component's WorkManager say EJB_WM* if one is defined.

Remember the execute thread remains the same - so once a request has come in, the same thread will execute the servlet, and then the EJB.

In my sample app, I'm firing 50 concurrent calls to an index.jsp, whereas in the `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`, I've defined this constraint for the EJB alone

```
<work-manager>
       <name>WorkManagerA</name>
       <max-threads-constraint>
          <name>MyMaxThreadCount</name>
          <count>1</count>
       </max-threads-constraint>
    </work-manager>
```

I can see the logs showing 2 parallel calls in different threads 6 and 8 within index.jsp

```
INDEX.JSP - Current ThreadName Is: [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'

INDEX.JSP - Current ThreadName Is: [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
```

Now some more log statements

```
Calling EJB from index.jsp 1317985368088[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
Start EJB 1317985368088[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
end EJB 1317985368088[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'

Calling EJB from index.jsp 1317985368088[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
Start EJB 1317985368104[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
end EJB 1317985368104[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
```

As the timestamps (System.currentTimeMillis()) show, index.jsp has been called at the same time 1317985368088 from Threads 6 and 8, however the
System.out.println statements called "Start EJB" and "end EJB" have a different timestamp for Threads 6 and 8. These are from within the EJB.

This shows the EJB WorkManager is doing it's task of constraining the Parallel Thread Count to only 1 at a time